# ChartJS: Mapping Non numeric Y and X

Tags: charts, chart.js, scatter-plot, linechart, scatter

I'm trying to map non numeric y and x and for some reason it does not work.

E.g.

```
xLabels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
yLabels: ['Request Added', 'Request Viewed', 'Request Accepted', 'Request Solved', 'Solving Confirmed'],
```

And when i try to change:

```
data: ['Request Added', 'Request Viewed']
```

with

```
data: [{x: "January", y: 'Request Added'}, ...]
```

Graph does not show a thing

Also i tried to use scales.yAxis.ticks.callback to modify and map against an array but that didnt work out either.

```
[0: 'Request Added', 1: 'Request Viewed']
```

EDIT: Essentially I need something like this

```
Request Added           x           x
Request Viewed                 x
Request Accepted               x    x
                    January, Feb, March
```

Basically a copy of this: https://answers.splunk.com/answers/85938/scatter-plot-with-non-numeric-y-values.html

Which also suggests to map against an array, but the callback in Y-ticks makes no freaking sense.. ? As i add `labelY : [1,2,3,4,5,6]` The Third argument of callback "values" is equal to `[-2-1 0 1 2]`.

Comment: Can you show a fiddle with your efforts?

Comment: Did it locally with examples/non-numeric-y.html :/ Not much to show. I tried all kinds of variations and then stashed em

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use a category scale for both the X and Y axis, you must use the traditional data format of an array of values.  Per the [chart.js api docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-scatter-line-charts)...

> Scatter line charts can be created by changing the X axis to a linear axis. To use a scatter chart, data must be passed as objects containing X and Y properties

This implies that you can only use the data format `{x: ' ', y: ' '}` when at least the X axis is a linear scale (but I'm betting it only works if both the X and Y axis are linear).

Since you are limited to only using an array of values for your data, you must use at least 2 datasets in order to plot multiple values on the X axis (like what you are trying to do).

Here is a chart configuration that gives what you are looking for.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var myLine = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    xLabels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    yLabels: ['Request Added', 'Request Viewed', 'Request Accepted', 'Request Solved', 'Solving Confirmed'],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      data: ['Request Added', 'Request Viewed', 'Request Added'],
      fill: false,
      showLine: false,
      borderColor: chartColors.red,
      backgroundColor: chartColors.red
    }, {
      label: "My First dataset",
      data: [null, 'Request Accepted', 'Request Accepted'],
      fill: false,
      showLine: false,
      borderColor: chartColors.red,
      backgroundColor: chartColors.red
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title:{
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js - Non Numeric X and Y Axis'
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Month'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        type: 'category',
        position: 'left',
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Request State'
        },
        ticks: {
          reverse: true
        },
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

You can see what it looks like from this [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/EWdrWR).

If you are for whatever reason tied to using the `{x: ' ', y: ' '}` dataformat, then you will have to change both your scales to linear, map your data to numerical values, then use the [`ticks.callback`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-common-configuration) property to map your numerical ticks back to string values.

Here is an example that demonstrates this approach.

```
var xMap = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
var yMap = ['Request Added', 'Request Viewed', 'Request Accepted', 'Request Solved', 'Solving Confirmed'];

var mapDataPoint = function(xValue, yValue) {
  return {
    x: xMap.indexOf(xValue),
    y: yMap.indexOf(yValue)
  };
};

var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
var myLine2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      data: [
        mapDataPoint("January", "Request Added"),
        mapDataPoint("February", "Request Viewed"),
        mapDataPoint("February", "Request Accepted"),
        mapDataPoint("March", "Request Added"),
        mapDataPoint("March", "Request Accepted"),
      ],
      fill: false,
      showLine: false,
      borderColor: chartColors.red,
      backgroundColor: chartColors.red
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js - Scatter Chart Mapping X and Y to Non Numeric'
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Month'
        },
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: xMap.length - 1,
          callback: function(value) {
            return xMap[value];
          },
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Request State'
        },
        ticks: {
          reverse: true,
          min: 0,
          max: yMap.length - 1,
          callback: function(value) {
            return yMap[value];
          },
        },
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

You can see this in action at the same [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/EWdrWR).